# What is the figure of speech used in these lines?

Tags: poetry, figures-of-speech

> **Jacob's Ladder**
>
> Hearken! Trim that swagger a trifle, you wretched lump of earth!
> Stamp those feet neither, nor act so haughty
>
> Hearken! You are but a tiny figure on the grand scroll
> A statistic, a number— a one-in-a trillion figure
> Cometh before you a legion did
>
> Hearken! You canst begin to count them graves!
> The **die was rolled eons back, and the die is cast**
>
> Hearken! Shrug off those **epaulets of hubris, those self-congratulatory badges**
> You insignificant statistic you— ashes to ashes, dust to dust!

What is the figure of speech the poet has used in the highlighted parts? Also, what is the point of the poem and why is it titled so? I may be wrong but I thought the whole poem was rather a doggerel.

Comment: Yes, the style is a bit dated: *Be humble*. Those bolds are metaphors for games of chance and signs of military pride. The title? You think you're up for fighting angels all night?

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Yosef Baskin.

Comment: Pointy poem painfully pierces people's pride.

Comment: The grammar of the obsolete English is, however, incorrect in two cases here. "Cometh" is present tense so should not be coupled with "did" and "canst" is the second person singular of "can" so should be used with the first person singular "thou". Written by a modern person with an incomplete understanding of 16th and 7th century English or emulating a person with such an understanding.

Comment: @BoldBen: Thank you for pointing out the errors; they eluded me. But i was positive in my mind that this is doggerel. Some poetaster must have written it. And I can't make much sense of the title either.

Comment: So _cometh_ means _come/comes_. What is its past form? @BoldBen

Comment: @user405662 [You **must** credit quoted authors](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) with their name and the source of the work (and preferably a link if it's available online).

Comment: @Andrew Leach: Apologies, dear Andrew. Will surely be mindful of this in future.

Comment: The poem stinketh to the heavens. But if it's literary criticism you want, EL&U might not be the best forum. Perhaps our sister site, https://literature.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @rajah9: I would appreciate it if you elaborated a bit more on  the poem's "stench" :) I mean why it stink and all that. :)

Comment: IMO, Poetry should help reveal something of the poet's thinking and engage the reader. This poem reveals a haughty, condescending attitude from the poet, and insults rather than engages the reader. There's nothing that encourages me to shrug off my "epaulets of hubris" when the poet's hubris is so glaringly displayed.

Comment: @user405662 "Cometh" means "comes" not "come". It's past tense is "came" or "hath come".

Comment: @BoldBen: Thanks. Just this bit too, please: what's wrong with _you canst_?

Comment: As I said "canst" is the second person _singular_ of the verb "can". Before the 18th, or perhaps the late 17th centuries the word 'you' was used pretty much in the way the French still use 'vous'. That is it was the second person _plural_ and the respectful second person singular. You would call your friends, family and social inferiors "thou" or "thee" (depending on case, "thee" being the a accusative). During the social disruption of the late 17th century it became difficult to work out who you needed to regard as social superiors so the familiar singular was dropped for safety's sake.

Comment: @user405662 The dropping of the familiar form in all but some dialect speech (it survived into the late 20thC in Derbyshire dialect at least including the question "canst tha do that?") conceals a significant element of Christian doctrine in the 1662 version of the Lord's Prayer where God the Father (surely the entity most deserving of respectful address) is referred to using the second person familiar possessive 'thy' in "hallowed be _thy_ name". The Quaker sect took this further refusing to use "you" in the singular at all. Their founder addressed Charles II as "thee, Charles Stuart"

Comment: @Andrew Leach: Kindly delete this question. I tried, but I'm unable to.

Comment: You're not able to delete this because there is an answer with a positive score. For that reason, moderators won't delete it either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***1. What is the figure of speech the poet has used in the highlighted parts?***

**"Die has been rolled eons back, and the die cast"** is an ***[antanaclasis](https://literarydevices.net/antanaclasis/)***, a rhetorical scheme, literary device, or "figure of speech," as it were, where the identical word is repeated but each time using a different definition. In the first instance, "[die](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/die)" is defined as a small multisided object used in games of chance, the plural of which is "dice," and in the second instance, "[die](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/die)" is defined as a casting mold used for manufacturing an item or items, the plural of which is "dies."

**"Epaulets of hubris, those self-congratulatory badges"** is a ***[transferred epithet](https://www.bbc.co.uk/bitesize/topics/zmfc7ty/articles/zhrsf4j#:%7E:text=Transferred%20epithet%20is%20when%20an,thing%20is%20transferred%20to%20another.&text=Epithets%20are%20usually%20adjectives%20like,noun%20like%20%27Happy%20birthday%27.)***, a rhetorical scheme where a description of one thing is transferred onto something else. It's not actually the epaulets that are "of hubris" since epaulets are inanimate objects that are incapable of hubris. It's not actually the badges that are "self-congratulatory" since badges are likewise inanimate objects that are incapable of congratulating themselves. Rather, it's the person wearing the epaulets and the badges that is being described as "of hubris" and "self-congratulatory," those epithets transferring between the person wearing those objects and those objects.

***2. Also, what is the point of the poem?***

The **point of the poem**, *in my own humble opinion*, is to humble — or even humiliate — the reader, to take us each down a notch, to make us each feel not at all special, to get us each down off any high horse any of us may have fancied to climb upon.

***3. And why is it titled so?***

The title "**Jacob's Ladder**" is a Bible reference to a dream the prophet Jacob had, (recounted in [Genesis 28](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%2028&version=KJV)) in which he saw a ladder (recounted in [verse 12](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%2028%3A12&version=KJV)) leading to heaven. The poem is apparently asserting that that ladder is *extremely* crowded, a trillion-souls-crowded even, so any of us readers considering ourselves to one day find ourselves on it makes none of us anything special, just another face in an almost unfathomably numerous horde, so certainly nothing worthy of self-congratulations or hubris.

Comment: I would have read the two uses of "die" as having the same meaning, as that's the usual sense of "the die is cast"

Comment: @user888379 "Die" here is the singular of "dice". However "dice" is often used as both  a singular and a plural noun now. Out of interest a "die" can also mean a mould or former in metalworking. Screw threads are cut into plain rod with a "die" for example but if you asked a metalworker to lend you his "dice" he'd be confused, metalworking "dies" are pluralised with an "s". All very confusing.

Comment: When Julias Caesar crossed the Rubicon (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossing_the_Rubicon) "he is said to have uttered the phrase *alea iacta est* — 'the die is cast'" The die cast is a gambling cube, not a manufacturing mold.

Comment: @rajah9: I find the poem confusing and lacking in merit from the perspective of prosody, metaphor choice, and in general— to be frank. Your thoughts?

Comment: @rajah9 Absolutely, I was just pointing out that there is another meaning of "die" which has a different plural. I was also pointing out that these days "die" is rarely used for a single gambling cube, nowadays most people would say "You play Ludo by throwing _a dice_". Strictly it's wrong but most people would find difficulty recognising "You play Ludo by throwing a _die_". Most of the minority of people who have come across 'die' at all would think "Play a game by throwing a thread cutter? How does that work?"

Comment: I find you're off the mark BoldBen. "Die" as a singular of "dice" is common and understood. I've never said "a dice." With family or friends, if playing a game with a singular die, what's said is "die" (e.g., "Hand me the die."). In fact, if someone said "dice," someone almost certainly would say, "It's a 'die,' not 'a dice,'" which would likely lead to chat about how "dice" is now technically acceptable but then so is saying "irregardless" for "regardless" since common error's led to it being defined as "regardless" in the dictionary, others then rejecting the propagation of such idiocy, etc.